# How to do pagination in fragment recyclerview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

```
    class FragmentAssignAccDetails :
          BaseFragment<FragmentAssignAccDetailsBinding, AssignAccountViewModel>(),
          AssignAccountNavigator {
    @Inject
    var mViewModel = AssignAccountViewModel()
    var searchAccRequest: AccountRequest? = null
    private var isLoading = false
    private var isLastPage = false
    private var totalCount = 0
    private var accountDetailsAdapter: AccountDetailsAdapter? = null
    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_assign_acc_details
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInsta`enter code here`nceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        init()
    }
    
    override fun onSearchAccountClicked() {
        var accnameVal = accountname.text.toString()
        when {
            tv_search_label.text.equals(resources.getString(R.string.tv_account_name)) -> {
                accnameVal = accountname.text.toString()
            }
        }
        activity?.let {
            when (mViewModel.validateAccountNo(accountname.text.toString())) {
                1 -> {
                    UIUtils.showToast(it, resources.getString(R.string.enter_acc_name_number))
                }
                0 -> {
                    hideKeyboard()
                        searchAccRequest = AccountRequest(
                            "", "", "", accnameVal.trim(), "", "", "", "", "", "", 0, 20
                        )
                        if (searchAccRequest != null) {
                            AppAnalytics.accountSearchButtonClickEvent(
                                it,
                                ApplicationDB.get().getUserData()?.user_login_s.toString(),
                                true,
                                accnameVal.trim()
                            )
                            mViewModel.searchRequest(searchAccRequest)
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    override fun onSearchAccountSuccess(responseData: AccountResponse) {
            activity?.let {
                if (progress_account != null) {
                    UIUtils.showProgress(it, progress_account, false)
                }
            }
            if (totalCount == 0) {
                totalCount = responseData.total_results
            }
            if (responseData.result.isNotEmpty()) {
                populateData(responseData)
                if (activity != null) {
                    accountDetailsAdapter?.addAll(responseData.result)
                }
            } else {
                activity?.let { UIUtils.showToast(it, resources.getString(R.string.no_records)) }
                    if (lobAndPPLData?.account_search_by.equals(getString(R.string.searchby_accnt_name))) {
                        btn_create_account.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }
                    fragss_rc_searchresultaccount.visibility = View.GONE
                    fragss_rc_table1.visibility = View.GONE
                    edit_optydetail.visibility = View.GONE
                    columnheading1.visibility = View.GONE
            }
    }
    
    
    private fun loadMoreApiCall() {      
        activity?.let {
            if (NetworkUtils.isNetworkConnected(it)) {
                searchAccRequest?.offset = accountDetailsAdapter!!.getSize()
                mViewModel.searchRequest(searchAccRequest)
            } 
        }
    }
    
    private fun init() {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            fragss_rc_searchresultaccount?.layoutManager = layoutManager
            fragss_rc_searchresultaccount?.adapter = accountDetailsAdapter
            fragss_rc_searchresultaccount?.addOnScrollListener(object :
                PaginationScrollListener(layoutManager) {
                override fun isLastPage(): Boolean {
                    return isLastPage
                }
                override fun isLoading(): Boolean {
                    return isLoading
                }
                override fun loadMoreItems() {
                    isLoading = true
                    if (accountDetailsAdapter!!.getSize() < totalCount) {
                        loadMoreApiCall()
                    }
                })
        }
        private fun populateData(data: AccountResponse) {
                btn_create_account.visibility = View.GONE
                fragss_rc_searchresultaccount.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                val accountDetailList = ArrayList<ResultX>()
                for (element in data.result) {
                    accountDetailList.add(element)
                }
                fragss_rc_searchresultaccount.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
                    activity?.applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false
                )
                accountDetailsAdapter = activity?.let {
                    AccountDetailsAdapter(it,
                        accountDetailList,
                        object : AccountDetailsAdapter.Listener {
                            override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
                                val fname = accountDetailList[position].primary_contact.first_name
                                val lname = accountDetailList[position].primary_contact.last_name
                                accountDetails = AccountDetailsRequest(
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.taluka,
                                    accountDetailList[position].account_id,
                                    accountDetailList[position].account_name,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.address_line_1,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.city,
                                    accountDetailList[position].main_phone_number,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.address_line_2,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.district,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.pincode,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.state.code,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.state.name,
                                    accountDetailList[position].site_name,
                                    accountDetailList[position].address_id,
                                    accountDetailList[position].primary_contact.contact_id,
                                    accountDetailList[position].primary_contact.mobile_number,
                                    "$fname $lname",
                                    accountDetailList[position].address.state.name,
                                    accountDetailList[position].account_type,
                                    accountDetailList[position].arn_number,
                                    accountDetailList[position].account_segment
                                )
    
                                AppAnalytics.accountSearchSuccessEvent(
                                    context = it,
                                    user_id = ApplicationDB.get()
                                        .getUserData()?.user_login_s.toString(),
                                    account_id = accountDetails?.acc_id,
                                    account_number = accountDetails?.phone,
                                    account_name = accountDetails?.name,
                                    name = accountDetails?.contact_name,
                                    city = accountDetails?.city,
                                    taluka = accountDetails?.Taluka,
                                    district = accountDetails?.district,
                                    contact_id = accountDetails?.contact_id,
                                    contact_number = accountDetails?.contact_number,
                                    addressLine1 = accountDetails?.address_line_1,
                                    state = accountDetails?.state,
                                    account_segment = accountDetails?.account_segment,
                                )
                            }
                        })
                }
                init()
        }
    }
```

Xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModelAssignAccDetails"
            type="xyz.viewmodel.AssignAccountViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".ui.opportunity.fragment.AssignFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragss_rc_searchresultaccount"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dim_5"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dim_5"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linBottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Need your help that we have to scroll down the list and paginate the next records but eventually while scrolling new records replaces the previous records
here what i did is onSearchAccountSuccess() i have updated the accountDetailsAdapter and also have the populateData() function in populateData() set an adapter value and in below called init() function where scrolling pagination code is available
recycler view id is fragss_rc_searchresultaccount
adapter is accountDetailsAdapter
here usually init() should be called in onViewCreated() but it does work
stucked with this from last 4 days
need help!!!
Note:removed unwanted code